# Python module won't install

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

This is my `setup.py` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
from sys import path

setup(name= 'conundrum',
    version= '0.1.0',
    author= 'elssar',
    author_email= 'elssar@altrawcode.com',
    py_modules= ['conundrum'],
    url= 'https://github.com/elssar/conundrum',
    license= 'MIT',
    description= 'A framework agnostic blog generator.',
    long_description= open(path[0]+'/README.md', 'r').read(),
    install_requires= [
        'PyYAML >= 3.0.9',
        'Markdown >= 2.2.0',
        'requests >= 1.0.4',
        ],
)
```

I have tried using both `setuptools` and `distutils`, but this won't install my module. Instead I get

```
file module.py (for module module) not found
```

This is my directory structure

```
/module
|--/test
|--README.md
|--license.txt
|--module.py
|--setup.py
```

Just to be clear, module is the root directory.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is the output when I try to install

```
elssar@elssar-laptop:/usr/local/src/conundrum$ sudo python /home/elssar/code/conundrum/setup.py install
/usr/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py:250: UserWarning: 'licence' distribution option is deprecated; use 'license'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to conundrum.egg-info/requires.txt
writing conundrum.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to conundrum.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to conundrum.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found
file conundrum.py (for module conundrum) not found
reading manifest file 'conundrum.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'conundrum.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
file conundrum.py (for module conundrum) not found
file conundrum.py (for module conundrum) not found
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying conundrum.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying conundrum.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying conundrum.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying conundrum.egg-info/requires.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
copying conundrum.egg-info/top_level.txt -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist/conundrum-0.1.0-py2.6.egg' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' to it
removing 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg' (and everything under it)
Processing conundrum-0.1.0-py2.6.egg
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/conundrum-0.1.0-py2.6.egg' (and everything under it)
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/conundrum-0.1.0-py2.6.egg
Extracting conundrum-0.1.0-py2.6.egg to /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
conundrum 0.1.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/conundrum-0.1.0-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for conundrum==0.1.0
Searching for requests==1.0.4
Best match: requests 1.0.4
Adding requests 1.0.4 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Searching for Markdown==2.2.0
Best match: Markdown 2.2.0
Processing Markdown-2.2.0-py2.6.egg
Markdown 2.2.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing markdown_py script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Markdown-2.2.0-py2.6.egg
Searching for PyYAML==3.10
Best match: PyYAML 3.10
Adding PyYAML 3.10 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Finished processing dependencies for conundrum==0.1.0
```

Just to be sure there isn't something wrong my my system, I downloaded two packages from github with a similar `setup.py` and installed them. Installed without any problems.

Comment: What commands are you using to install and what errors are you getting?

Comment: @Mike that is the only error I get. Other than that there are a couple of warnings.

Comment: @elssar: What are the warnings? And what's the traceback on the error? Maybe you think none of that is relevant, and maybe you're right, but you could be wrong—if you knew exactly what was happening here, you wouldn't be asking this question. So please, give us the actual command you're running and the full output.

Comment: Also, please give us your actual `setup.py`, or a stripped-down but still-runnable version that still demonstrates the problem. Because what you've shown will fail with a `NameError` on the `dependencies` line. And, if you get rid of that, it will work just fine.

Comment: @abarnert question updated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I cannot run `setup.py` from a different directory. It needs to be run from the directory it is in. That was the problem here.

Fixed.

Comment: OK. I just assumed that you knew that `module.py` would be `$(pwd)/module.py`, not `$(dirname /path/to/setup.py)/module.py`. But that wasn't a very good assumption. Unix tools do it far more often that way than the other way, but that's not the same as "it can only be that way" (especially for Windows users). (BTW, the same is true if you use a relative path in `package_dir`—it's relative to the pwd.) Do you think the docs need to make this clearer? If so, you may want to file a documentation bug, or bring it up on the mailing lists.

Comment: @abarnert I know where `module.py` is, I just assumed that `setup.py` would automatically read from its root directory and install in the current working directory. I'll have to read the docs again, carefully, to see if this isn't already written somewhere. I think half my problems are as a result of my haphazard process of reading between the lines from multiple sources and then looking at code examples to figure out what is happening without understanding what it does.

Comment: @elssar: I couldn't find anywhere it was said explicitly in the docs; I think they just make the same assumption I did. But I, like you, didn't exactly peruse them in detailed scrutiny.

Comment: This solution also worked for my docker container. In the DockerFile, instead of "RUN python /package/setup.py install", I needed "WORKDIR /package" and then "RUN python setup.py install"

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your layout, the problem is that you're using the default `package_dir`, which means that top-level modules like `module` need to be in the root directory as `module.py`, not as `module/module.py`.

So, add this:

```
package_dir = {'': 'module'}
```

Now, it'll look for `module` as `module/module.py`.

(PS, this would all be a lot less confusing to discuss if your module, or its subdirectory, or ideally both, were called something other than "module". Also, if you used a more standard format for drawing your directory tree.)

This is explained in [Listing whole packages](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages). (I realize you're listing individual modules, not whole packages, but the docs for that section just say "again, you can override the package/directory correspondence using the package_dir option", referring back to the section I linked. And the [reference](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=package_dir) for `package_dir` is even less helpful; it just says "A mapping of package to directory names".)

Comment: It doesn't deserve to be a second answer, but I found the [The Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging 1.0 - Creating a Package](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) to be helpful as a skeleton for developing a package structure.

Comment: @Mike: IIRC, that guide avoids explaining all of the complicated stuff, and instead explains how to avoid needing the complicated stuff—which means it probably won't directly answer the OP's question, but could easily lead him to not need the answer anymore. (And, even if it doesn't, it's worth reading.) So, definitely +1.

Comment: @Mike Guess I should've been more clearer--> module is the root directory, it has the same name as module.py. To be clearer - the root directory is named module and it contains the python script module.py and everything else, and a sub directory with the tests, which I don't need installed.

Comment: @Mike I've read that guide, but the tutorial requires I make another directory, and an `__init__.py` file, which would be empty as I don't need anything initialized.

Comment: @elssar An empty `__init__.py` file is perfectly valid - it indicates to python that the directory is a package.

Comment: @Mike: Yes, but I don't think the OP wants to create a package, just a module. (He wants to be able to `import module`, not `import module.module` after installing.)

Comment: @elssar: In that case, you're going to have to give us your actual `setup.py` and the full error message. Because when I try your file with that layout, I get an error about that undefined `dependencies`—and, once I fix that, everything works (except for a warning about using `licence` instead of `license`). In particular: `copying module.py -> build/lib`.