# I am having some difficulties for installing pyglet for python 3

Tags: python, pyglet

I am having some difficulties for installing pyglet for python 3.
I write into CMD: "[the setup.py filepath] install"

[image: here is an image of the text]

I have tried re-installing the pyglet file many times, but it always gets stuck on this error.
I'm still new to most of the complicated ways that things work, so try to make your answers clear and simple.

Comment: Have you tried using `pip`?

Comment: then it says: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you on windows?  If so try: `python -m pip install pyglet`

Comment: @AleKid, before running that command, make sure *you are in* the `pyglet` directory that contains the `setup.py` file: see this answer: [Python module won't install](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14867310/1248974)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by 'in the directory'. anyway, then it claims that python is not recognised.

Comment: I'm assuming windows because the backslash in the path. When installing Python get you get the option "Add Python to system PATH", make sure you check that box. Also make sure `pip` is checked when installing Python.
After that, reboot the PC, open a command promt **as administrator** and run `pip install pyglet`.

Comment: so, i have to reinstall python? How do i do that?