# Unable to install python module: warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

Tags: python

I am attempting to install this [python package](https://github.com/cbtolson/ensemblerna_package/tree/master) in a conda virtual environment.

Running: `sudo python setup.py install`

Yields the following error: `warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install`

Here's the relevant part of the output:

```
 self.initialize_options()
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing ensemblerna.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to ensemblerna.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to ensemblerna.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to ensemblerna.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'ensemblerna.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'ensemblerna.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-11.0-arm64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib' does not exist -- no Python modules to install
```

Here are the contents of the setup.py file:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
      name='ensemblerna',
      version='1.0',
      author='Chanin Tolson Woods',
      author_email='laederachlab@gmail.com',
      description='A package for the visualization and comparison of RNA structural ensembles',
      license='GPL (>= 2)',
      keywords='visualization rna structural ensemble',
      url='https://www.ribosnitch-ensemblerna.rhcloud.com',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['examples']),
      install_requires=['numpy', 'matplotlib', 'scipy', 'scikit-learn', 'jinja2', 'IPython', 'mpld3'],
      scripts=['bin/ensemblerna'],
      zip_safe=False
)
```

After running setup.py install, a build/scripts-3.9 direcotry is generated, containing one file with these contents:

```
from ensemblerna.main import main

if (__name__=="__main__"):
    main()
```

Others have pointed out that one must run `setup.py` in the directory containing the file, [as in this thread for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865990/python-module-wont-install), but this doesn't fix the problem.

Is the problem that I'm attempting to do this in a virtual environment? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This sounds more like your custom package is not setup correctly or the code is wrong, but you did not include any more information or actual code, so not sure what you expect from us.

Comment: how does the package look like you are trying to install? is there a build/lib folder?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy sorry for the lack of information. I've edited the post to provide more detail. Thanks.

Comment: @tobifasc after running setup.py install, a build folder is generated, containing another folder called 'scripts-3.9', with one file. I updated the original post with the contents of that file.

Comment: quick FYI that `sudo python setup.py install` works without conda venv, so the package itself is not the issue